# Function stopping before if statement

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a function that allows someone to guess the value of the variable `z` which is an integer. This is what I have written so far:

```
z = 31
puts "Guess the number that z represents. \nPick a number"
get_s = Integer(gets.chomp)
s = get_s
puts "you chose #{s}. Thanks"
if s < z
  print  s + " is less than z"
elsif s > z 
  print  s + " is higher than z"
else
  print s + " is equal to z. Congratulations!"
end
```

When I run this code, it asks for the integer for `get_s` and then prints it. At that point the program ends. Obviously, I'm missing something. How do I get it to move on to the next part of the code?

Also, is there a way that I can get it to repeat the sequence until they guess the right number?

Comment: That's not a java code

Comment: The title asks about Java and the contents ask about Ruby. Are you using JRuby? Please tag appropriately. In its current form, this question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: yeah, by using a loop. look into *while-loop* and *break*.

Comment: apologies, you are correct it is Ruby

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is *not a discussion forum*. We don't care about your level of experience, as it is not relevant to *the question you are asking*; and we don't care about why you want to solve the problem (unless it is either [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/), or admittedly something unusual that goes against normal programming practice). We *do* care about your *single* (if you have to write "also", that's a red flag), specific question about the code.

Comment: As this is not a discussion forum, it is also not a particularly good place to learn the fundamentals. It is best to [try to research and solve problems yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), and if you are just starting to learn then you should follow a tutorial for your language. There are certain things you need to learn how to do, and a certain order that makes sense to learn them in, and you don't necessarily know about all those things or that order (or you wouldn't be in this position).

Comment: If you really must find out how to apply some technique that you suspect is basic, you can also try using a search engine to look it up. For example, you could look for `ruby if statement doesn't run`, or `ruby restart program`, etc.

Comment: Another useful skill is https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, which can start with looking for inconsistencies in how you have written the code. For example, it appears that you are using both `puts` and `print` to try to display information on the screen. What do you expect each of these to do? Are they appropriate for the situations where you use them?

Comment: It's a good attempt. You need to make a few adjustments. Please add the error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting an error when running your code: `TypeError (String can't be coerced into Integer)`. This is because the `+` behaves differently for different types of objects in Ruby.

Think of `+` as a method in Ruby that acts on the object that precedes it. The `+` method for a string is concatenation. So `"hello " + "world"` becomes `"hello world"`. But the `+` method on an Integer is addition. This is why `34 + 21` is `55` and not `3421`. So Ruby is attempting to add a String to an Integer, which cannot be done.

Here's a way to test this out. Run `irb` from your command line and then try the following. The last two will give you errors but for different reasons.

```
34 + 21
"34" + "21"
34 + "21"
"34" + 21
```

What you want to use here is the interpolation operator: `#{}`. It evaluates an object so that it can be placed inside of a string.

```
if s < z
  print  "#{s} is less than z"
elsif s > z 
  print "#{s} is higher than z"
else
  print "#{s} is equal to z. Congratulations!"
end
```

Comment: OP, if you got an error when you ran your code, you should mention that explicitly, and show the complete error message. Most people would interpret "At that point the program ends" as meaning that *nothing observable* happens except that the program is no longer running.

Comment: Really appreciate the advice, I have made use of the curly braces and now understand why using the + sign was incorrect in this case. Just to clarify, there is no error message showing. It is as though the program stops running after receiving the first user input for the variable s.

Comment: Your standard error (stderr) is probably being rerouted to a file or some other place (/dev/null would be to ignore it).